# Issue using querulous "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twitter/conversions/time"

Tags: java, scala, sbt, querulous

I'm trying to use querulous in a project. It compiles fine using `sbt compile` but when I do `sbt run` I get:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twitter/conversions/time

Any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 1):

Usually because the jar containing the class in question is on the classpath at compile time, but not at runtime.  Investigate the `-classpath` parameter when calling scala.

Comment: Yes, or it can be due to having *different versions* of a jar in one environment vs the other.

Comment: Would the classpath change for sbt compile vs sbt run though?

Comment: Potentially.  Read this guy: http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/Classpaths